# Is there any way to monitor a specific library in linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, library

I would like to install phpmyadmin on a production server, and apt says it will uninstall libgd2.

In this case I know libgd2 is not used, but I've asked myself if in another case I would be able to check if the library is used (and I didn't know how to do that).

So, is there any way to check when, or how, or by whom, a library is used?

Thanks.

Edit: when I say 'being used' I mean accessed or called. Where I work some people use libraries that come with the system on their own programs, sometimes happens that a user asks for a library being installed by it's own name, then I need to install something that disagree with that library and I do not know if the user still uses it.

Comment: which distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Package management's the clean way to do this, but the this-is-a-nail-and-I-have-a-hammer approach would be something like:

```
find / -mode 755 -type f -exec ldd {} \; | grep libgd
```

I'm sure there's a better alternative to "-mode 755" to find anything 755/775/700/etc., but I don't know it offhand.  But this'll certainly work!

Comment: Interesting approach. But, did you mean -perm where you typed -mode?

Comment: Good point.  That's what I get for writing command lines from memory.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the distribution. Your wording suggests that you use Debian or Ubuntu. There, the answer is:

```
$ aptitude why libgd2-noxpm
i   trac-mastertickets Recommends trac-graphviz                                 
i A trac-graphviz      Depends    python-pygraphviz                             
i A python-pygraphviz  Depends    graphviz (>= 2.16)                            
i A graphviz           Depends    libgd2-noxpm (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg) | libgd2-xpm
                                   (>= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg)
```

Comment: Now, suppose you have trac-mastertickets installed but you are not using it. Is there any way to check if the library is beeing used?

Comment: $ grep-available -F Depends libgd2-noxpm -s Package